# Python Requests API Call Returning 0 elements

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to run an API call of the Ticketmaster API that will return a JSON of all of the events in a list of cities. The connection works (staus 200) but when I print the resulting JSON it has no elements. What is happening?

```
import requests


payload = {"city": ["Philadelphia", "Atlantic City"]}
tm_client = 
requests.get("https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=keyhere",
params=payload)
out=tm_client.json()
print(out)
```

Output looks like this:

```
{'page': {'totalElements': 0, 'totalPages': 0, 'size': 20, 'number': 0}, '_links': {'self': {'href': '/discovery/v2/events.json?city=Philadelphia%2CAtlantic+City'}}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it should return elements? Did you try a single city?

Comment: Have you tried moving your apikey into your payload and just requesting the base URL, checking the list of cities shouldn't be delimited in some sense, and double checking it's a get endpoint and not a post?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to move my apikey to my parameters but it fixed it! Thank you so much @JonClements